# How do I properly compile C++ with header using Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, header

I'm trying to build a program on macOS terminal with a header file. I have included the header on my cpp file. But I encountered error :

Error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here's the file I try to run

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "plot.h" //Header File 

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int PlotGraph(Mat & data) {

    //converting the Mat to CV_64F
    data.convertTo(data, CV_64F);
    Mat plot_result;

    Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plot = plot::Plot2d::create(data);
    plot->setPlotBackgroundColor(Scalar(50, 50, 50));
    plot->setPlotLineColor(Scalar(50, 50, 255));
    plot->render(plot_result);

    imshow("Graph", plot_result);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried change the compiler using `-c` , but still encounter the same error. Here's my makefile

Makefile :

```
BIN_DIR= .
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)
LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)

all: $(BIN_DIR)/trial1

$(BIN_DIR)/trial1: trial1.o
    ${CC} -o $(BIN_DIR)/trial1 trial1.o $(LIBS)

trial1.o: trial1.cpp
    ${CC} $(CFLAGS) -c trial1.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/trial1

allclean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/trial1
    rm -f Makefile
```

I tried with other simple program like "Hello World" and it compiled properly, but not this one. Any advice ?

Comment: Is that all of the code your compiling? Looks like you might need an `int main() {}`

Comment: Why would you want this line? `rm -f Makefile`?

Comment: @Galik I have several files I want compile with this makefile. In the example I just put 1 correspond to the file I failed to compile.

Comment: @Hiro Your make file should compile all the files in your program together. You don't write a seperate makefile for each file you want to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code you've put in your question is the entirety of `trail1.cpp` and judging from the linker error it seems you're missing a pretty simple thing...

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This function is required in every c/c++ program, and it must be called `main` (i.e. you can't change it to `PlotGraph`, you can make a separate function `PlotGraph` that gets called from `main()` but it's no substitute). You also have two options for main. As an alternative for the one above, you can do:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

(there's some freedom with how you define the const depending on how convenient vs how precise you want to be... ie you could also use `char const * const * const argv`, but that's another story)

As a final hint, you should probably make a backup of your Makefile as it looks like after you run `make allclean` your makefile will be gone and you will not be able to run `make` again due to the last line being `rm -f Makefile`